# iPhone: MKMapAnnotationView: Current location has the same annotationView as other pins. How to make it unique?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

Im using the following method to show MKAnnotation View on my mapView. But wehn I do that the current location of the user is also given the same view as the other pins. How can I make the current location a Unique pin color

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                                  initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    //annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

     UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
     myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
     myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
     myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    [myDetailButton addTarget:self 
                        action:nil/*@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)*/ 
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton;

    annView.animatesDrop=NO;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but: Instead of doing addTarget, handle the button press in the map view's own calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method which will give a reference to the annotation (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565197/how-to-find-which-annotation-send-showdetails for example).  Also, it's recommended to use dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier in viewForAnnotation to re-use views (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421663/exc-bad-access-with-mkpinannotationview/5421847#5421847 for example).

Comment: Thanks Anna Karenina. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewForAnnotation` method, check to see if the annotation is an instance of [MKUserLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If it is, return `nil`:

```
if ([annotation isMemberOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) return nil;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I tried this but I get an error which says "MKUserAnnotation undeclared"

Comment: I figured it out its [MKUserLocation class] instead of [MKUserAnnotation class]. Thanks it works now:)

Comment: @user - if this answer helped you or guided you to the correct answer, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's my fault. Should be MKUserLocation